# Silverlight Video Stretching

Tags: jquery, wpf, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-2.0

**What I want:**
To be able to resize the actual video inside the SL player with JS as I drag the corner.

**What I have so far:**
http://resopollution.com/granicus/silverlight_test/test_silverlight.html
(try dragging the corner, it crops the video, not resizing the video). I'm using jquery to dynamically resize the outer div and the OBJECT tag in here...

XAML:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
x:Class="VideoPlayer2.Page"
Width="640" Height="480">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FF282828">
    <MediaElement Source="Bear.wmv" Stretch="Uniform"/>
</Grid>
```

Any ideas if it's possible to be dynamically altering the actual size of the video itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your User Control has width and height predefined, and your grid is stretching to fill that without regard to the object tag size. Remove those.